# Multithreading crowds out other processes

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have added multithreading to a raytracer I am writing, and while it does run much faster now, when it's running, my computer is almost unusably slow. Obviously I want to use all my PC's compute power, but I don't want it to prevent any other application from getting access to the CPUs.

I thought about having the threads sleep, but unless they all sleep at the same time, then the other threads would just eat up the extra time. Also, I don't necessarily want to give up a certain percentage of available compute power if I'm not going to use it.

Also, (This is not my official question) I've noticed that for some reason the first thread launched does more work than the second, and the second more than the third, and so on until like the last 5 threads (out of 32) won't actually get a crack at any work, despite the fact that there's plenty to go a around (there's at least 0.5M work items for them to chew through). If someone would like to venture a guess in the comments, it would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you've oversubscribed your poor CPU. Try reducing the number of threads?

Comment: You could lower your program's priority.  What is your OS?

Comment: @Cameron That seems like it did the trick! I reduced my threads to 6, and now responsiveness is back to normal, and my timing on a frame actually decreased slightly (In addition, the workload across threads appears to be balanced now). I was under the impression that more threads couldn't hurt, but apparently that was incorrect. If you'd like to create an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Process and thread priorities were quite literally invented for this very purpose. Lower the priority of your raytracer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, my comment as an answer:

It sounds like you've oversubscribed your poor CPU. Try reducing the number of threads?

If there's significantly more threads than hardware cores, a lot of time is going to be wasted switching between threads, scheduling them in the OS, and in contention over shared variables. It would also cause the general slowdown of the other running programs, because they have to contend with the high number of threads from your program (which by default all have the same priority as the other programs' threads in the eyes of the OS scheduler).

Answer (score 2):

If you use the standard threads, you could try to use **[`thread::hardware_concurrency`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/hardware_concurrency/)** to find out an estimate of the maximul number of threads that are really supported by hardware, in order not to overload your cpu.

If it returns 0 the information is not available.  In other cases you could limit yourself to this number or a little bit below (thinking that other processes might use these as well).

If limiting the number of threads does not improve responsiveness, you can also consider calling from time to time [`this_thread::yield()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/this_thread/yield/) to give opportunity to reschedule threads.  But depending on the kind of job and synchronisation you use, this second alternative might decrease performance.